# How to test if a method was called?

Tags: java, junit

Is there a way to test if a method was executed without changing its code, even if there is no postconditon for it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your IDE / build process / needs, have a look at [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) and [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that (for instance) with Mockito.verify().

https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)

Answer (score 0):

If using an IDE, you can probably put a breakpoint in your method head or any of the body statements and then execute it. If the program stops there, it means your method is going to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood the question. Do you want to check if a method was called during the test?

If that's the case, it depends on your testing framework

- In mockito you can use [`verify`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1)
- In jmockit you can use [`verifications`](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r224/trunk/www/tutorial/AnExample.html#verifications)